# Copy reference without leading backslash

Tags: phpstorm

There is great feature in PhpStorm - `Copy Reference`. You put cursor inside class name => `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C` => Fully qualified class name gets into buffer. Miracle.

But class name is being copied with leading back slash, e.g. `\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container`.

Is there a way to make PhpStorm omit it?

**UPD**

Use case discussed in the tickets (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22279, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18100) is not my. Ans seems to me vary rarely. Seriously, I never used "Copy reference" feature for copying FQN into another namespace. How often did you? Autocomplete saves me in this case.

I use "copy reference" mainly for configuring Symfony2 service container.

Following notation for service definition is correct

`my.foo.bar.baz:
    class: My\Foo\Bar\Baz`

Meanwhile following

`my.foo.bar.baz:
    class: \My\Foo\Bar\Baz`

throws `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException` - "'\My\Foo\Bar\Baz'" is not a valid class name for the "my.foo.bar.baz" service".

What I'm asking for is not removing leading '\' at all. I see that it might be useful for somebody(even if use cases are note widely used).
It would be great if there was an option in PhpStorm settings - "Add leading '\'". And let it be turned on by default.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

As simple as **"No"**.

These tickets were closed as "Won't fix":

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22279
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18100

You can find argumentations there. But in short -- "Copy Reference" action will **always** copy **FQN**.

Comment: Thanks for reply and links. See updated original post.

Comment: You can complain **here** (about your special case or whatever) as much as you want -- it will not change anything, at all. It is a wrong place for that. Do you have arguments on why you think it is wrong? -- welcome to the JetBrain's Issue Tracker -- the place where users put feature request/bug report tickets and devs working on that.

Comment: But back to the subject: "Copy Reference" action is made for copying FQN. It is the same in **ALL** IDEs based on IDEA platform. This action was not meant to work the way you want to use it. Want options/change in behaviour? -- welcome to JetBrain's Issue Tracker.

Comment: @LazyOne Is there some function to get FQN for the currently opened class, if there is no namespace set at the top of it (and PSR-0 is used in the project)? I.e. how to generate current full namespace path inside the class file?

Comment: @Andrew I'm not 100% sure on exact case here .. but you can try invoking the same "Copy Reference" but on actual file instead of class -- it will copy the file path relative to the content root (in vast majority of cases you have only 1 content root in a project which is the project root). Then just delete `.php` from the end (if I understood whole situation correctly)

Comment: @LazyOne I tried, but the problem is that it copies reference with forward slashes and I need with backslashes...not good

Comment: Too bad. I think in most cases when I use the Copy reference function, I do it because the destination has no class autocompletion, when I type. It should be at least possible to provide an option the individual user can set.